# How to print title above pandas dataframe (.to_csv)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

How can I print different titles above two pandas dataframes in the same CSV? I tried print command but titles were printed in terminal instead of CSV.

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
 V = result
 W = reference
 H = np.random.random([5,5100])
 basis_mat, coef_mat = nmf_nimfa(V, W, H)

 basis_df = pd.DataFrame(data=basis_mat)
 coef_df = pd.DataFrame(data=coef_mat)

 with open('NMF_nimfa.csv', 'w') as f:
    print "Matrix 1"
    coef_df.to_csv(f)
 with open('NMF_nimfa.csv', 'a') as f:
    print "Matrix 1"
    basis_df.to_csv(f)
```

Answer (score 2):

If need write to file new rows with text use `write`:

```
with open('NMF_nimfa.csv', 'a') as f:
    f.write("Matrix 1 \n")
    coef_df.to_csv(f)
    f.write("Matrix 1 \n")
    basis_df.to_csv(f)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't specify the `path_or_buf` parameter when calling [.to_csv()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html) function - it'll return a string. So you can simply concatenate your title with returned CSV-string:

```
f.write("Matrix 1 \n" + oef_df.to_csv())
```

PS I'd recommend to use [@jezrael's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43423996/5741205) for huge DataFrames as my solution might potentionally cause `MemoryError` for big DFs